# Finitely generated $k$-algebra with vanishing module of differentials has Krull dimension zero

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have come across this question reading the answer to this question:  [An algebraic result corresponding to etale morphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/128422/742278).
How can I prove:

> Let $k$ be a field, R a finitely generated $k$-algebra. If the module of differentials $\Omega_{R/k}=0$, then R has Krull dimension zero.